# How to get POST fields in Express, without using bodyParser middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

With recent versions of Express, the recommendation (conveyed through a debug message) is to stop using the `bodyParser` middleware. I read a bit, and it looks like bodyParser is a wrapper to the `json` and `urlencoded` middlewares - and lo and behold, the most recent version of Express (3.4.4) uses these 2 instead of the `bodyParser` out of the box - splendid, right?

But now, I can't get to my fields. `req.body` is undefined. Here's my JS form submission code (text fields only, no files). Could someone please tell me which property/function of `req` do I use to get at the values?

```
var formData = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: '/myurl',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error('Error occured: ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: You could use [Busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) instead.

Comment: I wasn't aware of a warning against `bodyParser()`. There was one for `multipart()`, which has been deprecated. So, you can use the other 2 directly: `app.use(express.json()); app.use(express.urlencoded());`.

Comment: Thanks @adeneo, but is there a way to get at the values without including another resource?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I am using these 2 directly. But the `.body` is undefined. To see the warning, download the latest Express, and add `app.use(express.bodyParser())` to app.js.

Comment: The warning should say `connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0, connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0`, and you can still use BodyParser, everyone does, just make sure you delete temporary files, as that's the real issue.

Comment: @adeneo Still, the way to avoid this warning is to remove bodyParser(). I was expecting one of the other 2 to populate `.body`. Are you sayig I should continue using bodyParser and keep getting that warning?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue is that, when sending `FormData`, the `Content-Type` will be `multipart/form-data`.

Though you're using `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()`, each of them only acts on particular `Content-Type`s -- [`application/json`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.11.0/lib/middleware/json.js#L96) and [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.11.0/lib/middleware/urlencoded.js#L52), respectively.

And Express/Connect will be removing built-in support for `multipart()` and parsing of `multipart/form-data` content in the future due to security concerns. They instead [recommend using](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0):

> - [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable)
> - [connect-multiparty](https://github.com/superjoe30/connect-multiparty) or [multiparty](https://github.com/superjoe30/node-multiparty)
> - [connect-busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy) or [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy)

So, for future support of `FormData` and `multi-part` in general with Express/Connect, you'll have to use an addition dependency.

Comment: Changed the Ajax post contentType to 'application/json', sent the fields as a strigified json - and now it works! Cheers!