# How would you access form data without using bodyParser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I always see [bodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) being used to give you access to the posted form stuff. By making it accessible in `req.body`. But how would you access that data if you didn't want to use `bodyParser`?

Related/similar question - how does `bodyParser` provide you with the data in `req.body`?

Edit: I'm asking about how this stuff works on a low level. This [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228203/how-to-get-post-fields-in-express-without-using-bodyparser-middleware) seems to be addressing it by recommending certain middleware and describing how to use them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get POST fields in Express, without using bodyParser middleware?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228203/how-to-get-post-fields-in-express-without-using-bodyparser-middleware)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

bodyParser is a middleware that parses the stream of data to a json. 
I can't see a reason to not use bodyParser (if you don't want to handle multipart bodies), but you can parse the streaming by yourself if you want to. It will be something like the middleware below:

```
app.use(function( req, res, next ) {
  var data = '';
  req.on( 'data', function( chunk ) {
    data += chunk;
  });
  req.on( 'end', function() {
    req.rawBody = data;
    console.log( 'on end: ', data )
    if ( data && data.indexOf( '{' ) > -1 ) {
      req.body = JSON.parse( data );
    }
    next();
  });
});
```

If you want to parse multipart bodies you can use one of the following modules:

- busboy
- multiparty
- formidable
- multer

Comment: Adding this middleware causes my requests to timeout

Answer (score 2):

A cursory answer to this is to use https://github.com/stream-utils/raw-body to parse the request body and then run your JSON.parse on the result. This is how body-parser gets the request body from which it then parses json, urls, and raw text data.